# How to run test command and get no exception in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess

If I run this

```
test -d a
```

in Linux command line, it returns nothing and prints no error even if directory `a` doesn't exist, because the result is returned via exit code.

But if I want to grab this exit code with Python, I get

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call('test -d a')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/python27/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 168, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/python27/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 390, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/python27/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1025, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

How to overcome this? Changing command text is not allowed, anly python caller code should change. It shoudl return `0` or `1` depending on directory existence as described in manual.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue might be that Python cannot find `test -d a` rather than `test` failing and `subprocess.call` identifying the error and rasing an seemingly appropriate `OSError` exception. See the [exceptions](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/subprocess.html#exceptions) region of the `subprocess.call/Popen` docs. The right way to call it would be `subprocess.call(['test', '-d', 'a'])`